# Can we work out how fast we are traveling by looking at our mass?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, inertial-frames, mass-energy, speed

If we (the galaxy) were traveling close to the speed of light; relativity says we would need proportionally more energy to go faster. Given that relative to the cosmic microwave background, the Local Group is moving by 600 km/s; that's 0.2% of the speed of light. Is it possible to look at this in terms of mass/light speed.

i.e.light speed =infinite mass.
 .2% light speed =x mass.
stationary = mass.
x = speed

Comment: Space is expanding between galaxies, the galaxies themselves aren't 'moving' - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_factor_(cosmology)

Comment: How are you going to measure your mass in space?

Comment: Start with: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133376/why-is-there-a-controversy-on-whether-mass-increases-with-speed?, but this is a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/237269/can-absolute-speed-be-determined-by-an-objects-mass

Answer (score 4):

No, in our own frame (comoving frame) we are not moving at all. Even though the CMB radiation is defining a preferred frame, to us it looks like the CMB is moving with respect to us - that's why we see a kinematic dipole in the CMB maps: http://scienceblogs.com/startswithabang/2013/06/28/our-great-cosmic-motion/